# unable to get internet ftp server directory listing in android ftp client using apache commons library

Tags: android, ftp-client

I am getting a connection refused exception when i am trying to get directory listing from drivehq ftp server using my ftp client from android. Please help me and solve my problem. My code for this purpose is given below also i am testing on real device samsang galaxy mobile. Yes i have added these permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"/>
    public void login(String host,String username,String password,int port)
        {
            try 
            {
                ftpClient.connect(host);
                ftpClient.login(username, password);
                ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("/MyData");
                ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            } catch (SocketException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    public ArrayList<File> getDirectoryListing()
    {       
            ArrayList<File> list=new ArrayList<File>();
            FTPFile[] files = null;

            try
            {
                Log.d(ftpClient.printWorkingDirectory(), "is working directory");
                files=ftpClient.listFiles();
                for(FTPFile f:files)
                {
                    String s=f.getName();
                    Log.d(s, "is file");
                    File fs=new File(s);
                    list.add(fs);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return list;
        }
```

Comment: How is it being called?

Comment: What is this ftpClient object?

Answer (score 1):

I have used `ftp-4j` Library to upload my files to the server. You can use similar concept for your project. Here is the Link : [SampleDemo](https://github.com/Abhan/FTPS)

Thanks.